# Form tag in python script

Tags: python, html, cgi

this is a sample from my code:

```
   <form action="/public_html/newfriends.py" method="GET">

   with open("url of text file") as x:
     for line in x:
        print'<input type="checkbox" name="bemyfriend" value="friend"> %s <br>'%(line)


print"""
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

   </form>
   </body>
 </html>
"""
```

"Url of text file" refers to a HTML page where different usernames are listed, each one on a separate line. I din't include the beginning of my HTML code because it is working properly, it is just this one that I'm having trouble with.

This code should generate a list of checkbox with every username next to each checkboxes so that the logged in user can select the usernames he wants to add to his friend list. There should be a submit button after the list.

Thank you

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I've never used a form tag before. Is this the proper way to do it ? Should this work ?